# How to Save Application Class state

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-savedstate

I have a class that extends Application class Here is My Application class

```
public class UILApplication extends Application {
public int count_group;
public LoginUserInfo loginUserInfo = new LoginUserInfo();
public  static ArrayList<PostCategory> featuredCategory = new ArrayList<PostCategory>();
public ItemsAllPost selectedPost;

public PostCategory selectedCategory;
public PostCategory selectedSubCategory;
public ArrayList<PostCategory> categoryList = new ArrayList<PostCategory>();
public ArrayList<PostCategory> searchCategoryList = new ArrayList<PostCategory>();
public ArrayList<PostCategory> timePeriod = new ArrayList<PostCategory>();
public ArrayList<PostCategory> tagsList = new ArrayList<PostCategory>();
public ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> featuredPost = new ArrayList<ItemsAllPost>();
public ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> searchList = new ArrayList<ItemsAllPost>();
```

}

I have saved lot of data in it and using it in different Activity and Fragments

Now problem is When i press home button and come back to app after long time then it crashes.

Can anyone tell me how do i save this data when leaving the application and retain its state when i am back in application.

Please help.

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 2):

You generally should not put data in the `Application` class.  The lifetime of the `Application` instance is different from what most people assume, and you have no control over it.  Its lifetime is the same as the lifetime of the VM, though AFAIK this is not documented and could change without warning in the future.

As you've discovered, the `Application` instance might be destroyed any time your app goes into the background.  You will not be notified of this, since the `Application` has no `onSaveInstanceState(...)` or other shutdown lifecycle methods like activities do.

It's also possible that the `Application` will *not* be destroyed when all your activities have finished.  Android may keep the process and VM around, and your `Application` along with it.  If this happens, `onCreate()` will *not* be called again the next time your app is launched.

Comment: But how can i save Whole arraylist or class objects in it

Comment: @Android A `Service` might be appropriate.  Or maybe a SQLite database.  It really depends on the intended lifetime of the data.

Comment: So what should you use the Application class for?

Comment: @powder366 Only things that should have the same scope as the `Application` instance.  The point is that its scope is different from what most people assume, and you have no control over it.